# Context cleanup with apollo graphql server

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I can create a context function in `ApolloServer` that will be executed before each request.

How can I have a cleanup function (after request execution)?

Answer (score 2):

not sure if this is still relevant but I found this medium [article](https://stories.amazee.io/configuring-a-database-client-in-apollo-server-dc91556a17da) addressing this exact question.

You can use this snippet for when you want code to run after all the resolvers have run:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context: async ({ req }) => {
    ...
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      requestDidStart: () => ({
        willSendResponse: response => {
          // this will run after every request
          if (response.context.db) {
            response.context.db.close();
          }
        }
      })
    }
  ]
});
```

I looked in the docs and this plugin system is nowhere to be found. I haven't found anything to discourage use like this but it does not seem to be an official solution.

I tried it in my project and it does seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would like to have context cleanup function? The context is set before as the middleware for each request therefore if you would like to have context set differently for another request you just inject the logic to the middleware. Maybe i just do not understand your use case for this. It would be helpful if you can clarify why you would like to apply it? The context is set per request, therefore you can inject enmpty object for some requests based on the `req`. If you need to clear up information from req object after graphql middleware you can do for example another middleware where you will set req.user (if you have authenticated user there) to null.

Comment: I've achieved it with middleware, hence using apollo-server-express. I think the feature would be good to be supported directly in apollo-server. My use case is a database pool that I get a connection-per-request from it. I must close the connection in the request end.

Comment: One of the most common scenarios is closing the database connector (ex. Mongoose) after request